# Error When to load NAO model

Tags: ros, nao-robot, nao-driver, model

[image: Rosanswers logo]

**Hello Everyone!!**

I'm using:
https://github.com/ahornung/nao_robot

When tried to load it have this problem:

```
process[nao_walker-2]: started with pid [25682]

process[nao_sensors-3]: started with pid [25683]

process[nao_controller-4]: started with pid [25684]

[ERROR] [WallTime: 1380507862.005092] Error importing NaoQI. Please make sure that 
Aldebaran's NaoQI API is in your PYTHONPATH.

[ERROR] [WallTime: 1380507862.141412] Error importing NaoQI. Please make sure that    Aldebaran's NaoQI API is in your PYTHONPATH.

================================================================================

REQUIRED process [nao_walker-2] has died!

process has died [pid 25682, exit code 1, cmd     /home/vincent/fuerte/nao_robot/nao_driver/scripts/nao_walker.py --pip=127.0.0.1 -- 

pport=9559 __name:=nao_walker __log:=/home/vincent/.ros/log/6a2efe60-2977-11e3-926b- b8030561fc1f/nao_walker-2.log].

log file: /home/vincent/.ros/log/6a2efe60-2977-11e3-926b-b8030561fc1f/nao_walker-2*.log

Initiating shutdown!

================================================================================

[ERROR] [WallTime: 1380507862.217620] Error importing NaoQI. Please make sure that           Aldebaran's NaoQI API is in your PYTHONPATH.

[nao_controller-4] killing on exit

[nao_sensors-3] killing on exit

[nao_walker-2] killing on exit

[rosout-1] killing on exit

[master] killing on exit

shutting down processing monitor...

... shutting down processing monitor complete

done
```

**A lot of thanks!!!**

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/84446/error-when-to-load-nao-model/) by [vncntmh](https://answers.ros.org/users/4870/vncntmh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 52 on 2013-09-27

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

These lines are important:

```
[ERROR] [WallTime: 1380507862.005092] Error importing NaoQI. Please make sure that 
Aldebaran's NaoQI API is in your PYTHONPATH.

[ERROR] [WallTime: 1380507862.141412] Error importing NaoQI. Please make sure that    Aldebaran's NaoQI API is in your PYTHONPATH.
```

It seems that you didn't install naoqi, or you didn't add the API in your library path. ROS packages only provide the interface with naoqi, you still need the original APIs for Nao to get things work.

See this page:
http://wiki.ros.org/nao/Tutorials/Getting-Started#Installing_NAOqi

---

Originally posted by [Po-Jen Lai](https://answers.ros.org/users/1352/po-jen-lai/) with karma: 1371 on 2013-10-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [vncntmh](https://answers.ros.org/users/4870/vncntmh/) on 2013-10-09**:
Used:

```
 gedit .bashrc
```

And copy in the end

```
 export PYTHONPATH=~/naoqi/naoqi-sdk-1.12.3-linux32/lib:$PYTHONPATH
```

But have the same problem

**Comment by [Po-Jen Lai](https://answers.ros.org/users/1352/po-jen-lai/) on 2013-10-10**:
As AHornung said, you should install NaoQI python SDK in your PYTHON PATH. In /.~bashrc, it looks like  `PYTHONPATH=${PYTHONPATH}:/home/rosfuerte/tool/pynaoqi-python-2.7-naoqi-1.14-linux64`